# The excel file does not show changes when writing through ruby script using rubyXL

Tags: ruby, excel, rubyxl

```js
require "uri"
require "net/http"
require 'HTTParty' 
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'faker'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'rubyXL'

@workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("02.xlsx")
@worksheet = @workbook[0]
@worksheet.change_row_fill(0, 'FFFF00')
@workbook.write('02.xlsx')
```

This is my ruby script in which i am highlighting the first row. The problem is that the row is not highlighted when the file is already opened. But when i close the file and open it again the changes are there. Is there workaround to make the changes happen in real time when the file is already opened.

Comment: If the file is already open in Excel then you would need some kind of automation, where your code drives the Excel instance to make the changes.  Eg.  http://www.codeodor.com/index.cfm/2009/6/9/Automating-Excel-with-Ruby-A-Simple-Example/3030

Comment: @TimWilliams can you guide me to a mac example since i am not using windows.

Comment: I'm neither a mac nor a ruby user so I'd just be doing the same Googling you'll need to do.